# Auto-fill custom function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

So in my Google Sheet I have a custom function that just gets values from a json file. I'm trying to auto-fill 1 value in this function, but it doesn't work. I'm trying to achieve this:

```
=IMPORTJSON("example.json","1/value")
=IMPORTJSON("example.json","2/value")
=IMPORTJSON("example.json","3/value")
```

I would want it to autocomplete to 3,4,5 etc but it just repeats 1,2,3. I tried to put 1,2,3 in a separate cell then auto-fill those cells and just reference the cell in the function, but that doesn't work. Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use ROW() and & operator

```
=IMPORTJSON("example.json",ROW()&"/value")
```

ROW() returns the row number. If you need an offset, let say that you require `=IMPORTJSON("example.json","1/value")` of row 2, then use

```
=IMPORTJSON("example.json",(ROW()-1)&"/value")
```